# SQL Exact match with NULL or not null column

Tags: c#, sql

I have to delete or insert based on if row exist. But one of the columns could be `NULL` so if the values I'm passing is `Col 1: 123, Col 2: 345, Col 3: NULL` and this row exists delete it else insert. The problem is that `DBNull.Value` doesn't match the null column.

**Query**

```
@"IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM auth.UserPermissions ur WHERE ur.UserGroupId = @UserGroupId AND ur.ClientId = @ClientId AND ur.PermissionId = @PermissionId)
DELETE FROM auth.UserPermissions WHERE UserGroupId = @UserGroupId AND ClientId = @ClientId AND PermissionId = @PermissionId
ELSE
INSERT INTO auth.UserPermissions (ClientId, UserGroupId, PermissionId)
VALUES (@ClientId, @UserGroupId, @PermissionId)";
```

The column that could be `NULL` is `ClientId`. I can't use `AND (ur.ClientId = @ClientId OR ur.ClientId IS NULL)` because if I pass two objects where `Col 1: 123, Col 2: 345, Col 3: NULL` and `Col 1: 123, Col 2: 345, Col 3: 567` for **inserting** I'm going to **insert** the first one and when It comes to **insert** the second one the sql `IF` statement is going to return true and delete the row where `ClientId` is **NULL** and I'm passing `567` for `ClientId`.

How can I achieve that?

And my **cs**

```
var clientId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(_obj.ClientId) ? (object)DBNull.Value : _obj.ClientId;

string _query = @"IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM auth.UserPermissions ur WHERE ur.UserGroupId = @UserGroupId AND ur.ClientId = @ClientId AND ur.PermissionId = @PermissionId)
DELETE FROM auth.UserPermissions WHERE UserGroupId = @UserGroupId AND ClientId = @ClientId AND PermissionId = @PermissionId
ELSE
INSERT INTO auth.UserPermissions (ClientId, UserGroupId, PermissionId)
VALUES (@ClientId, @UserGroupId, @PermissionId)";

_command.CommandText = _query;
_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserGroupId", _obj.UserGroupId);
_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientId", clientId);
_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PermissionId", _obj.PermissionId);

await _command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(token);
_command.Parameters.Clear();
```

Comment: You shouldn't run this script, devide your SQL query into 2 queries(fetch, delete/insert)

Comment: Could you try Stored Procedure for this?

Comment: No, must be without SP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `col = @param OR (col IS NULL AND @param IS NULL)`:

```
IF EXISTS(
 SELECT 1
 FROM auth.UserPermissions ur 
 WHERE (UserGroupId=@UserGroupId OR(UserGroupId IS NULL AND @UserGroupId IS NULL))
 AND(ClientId=@ClientId OR(ClientId IS NULL AND @ClientId IS NULL))
 AND(PermissionId=@PermissionId OR(PermissionId IS NULL AND @PermissionId IS NULL))
)
DELETE FROM auth.UserPermissions 
WHERE (UserGroupId=@UserGroupId OR (UserGroupId IS NULL AND @UserGroupId IS NULL))
 AND(ClientId=@ClientId OR (ClientId IS NULL AND @ClientId IS NULL))
 AND(PermissionId=@PermissionId OR(PermissionId IS NULL AND @PermissionId IS NULL));
ELSE
INSERT INTO auth.UserPermissions (ClientId, UserGroupId, PermissionId)
VALUES (@ClientId, @UserGroupId, @PermissionId);
```